# Django authenticate always return None even if username and password are correct

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

I'm trying to do a web page using django. Where a user can register and login to the page. But When I try to login the authenticate function returns None even if the entered password and username are correct.
I'm using django version 2.1.2 and Python 3.5

I have tried adding
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)`
in settings.py

this is the function that I'm using for registration.

```
def SignUp(request):
    countryobj = Country.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        gr=request.POST.get('grade')
        if gr == 'Grade':
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Select Any Grade')
            return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html', {'form': form, 'countries': countryobj})

        if form.is_valid():
            print("hihihih")
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            username= request.POST.get('username')
            user.password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.student.birthdate = form.cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
            user.student.school_name = form.cleaned_data.get('school_name')
            user.student.individual = form.cleaned_data.get('individual')
            user.student.school_address = form.cleaned_data.get('school_address')
            user.student.country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
            user.student.state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
            user.student.communication_address = form.cleaned_data.get('communication_address')
            user.student.c_country = form.cleaned_data.get('c_country')
            user.student.c_state = form.cleaned_data.get('c_state')
            user.student.grade = form.cleaned_data.get('grade')
            user.student.cost = form.cleaned_data.get('cost')
            user.student.total = form.cleaned_data.get('total')
            user.student.type_user = form.cleaned_data.get('type_user')
            user.student.currency=form.cleaned_data.get('currency_code')
            user.save()
            subject = 'Registration Successfull'
            message = 'You have successfully completed registration....'+'\n'+'Username:' +user.username+'\n'+ 'Password:' +user.password
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [user.email]
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Registration Successfull .. Check E-mail for credentials')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
            return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html', {'form': form,'countries':countryobj})
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        print("lalala")
        # return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html')
        print(countryobj)
        return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html',{'form':form,'countries':countryobj})
```

This is the function that i use for login

```
class getLogin(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

            return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")
        else:
            return render(request,"authentication/signin.html")

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        usernamelog = User.objects.get(username=user)
        auth = authenticate(username=usernamelog, password=password)
        print("auth",auth)
        if auth:
            request.session['user']=auth.id
            request.session['grade']=auth.student.grade
            print("re",request.session['user'])
            print("ath",auth.username)
            request.session['username']=auth.username
            print("usr", request.session['username'])
            request.session['super']=auth.is_superuser
            print("ddd",auth.student.grade)
            # request.session['auth'] = auth.is_superuser
            if auth.is_superuser:
                return render(request,"app/admin.html")
            else:
                student_id=request.session['user']
                grade = request.session['grade']
                ex = Exam.objects.filter(level=grade)
                code = Code.objects.filter(student_id=student_id)

                return render(request, "app/student.html", {'link': ex, 'code': code,'profile':student_id})

        else:

            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Username or password mismatch')
            return redirect('login')
```

I'm not able to authenticate the user even the given username and password are correct

Comment: Assuming your CustomUserCreationForm inherits from the standard UserCreationForm, you successfully save the user - along with a correctly hashed password - but then *overwrite* all the successfully saved data with the same data again, failing to hash the password the second time. Why? What's the point of all those manual assignments after you've already saved the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as Daniel Roseman pointed out, you are overwriting the correctly saved user object with unhashed password. If you want to save the `Student` model, the you should call `user.student.save()` instead of `user.save()`.

```
def SignUp(request):
    countryobj = Country.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        gr=request.POST.get('grade')
        if gr == 'Grade':
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Select Any Grade')
            return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html', {'form': form, 'countries': countryobj})

        if form.is_valid():
            print("hihihih")
            user = form.save()
            user.student.birthdate = form.cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
            user.student.school_name = form.cleaned_data.get('school_name')
            user.student.individual = form.cleaned_data.get('individual')
            user.student.school_address = form.cleaned_data.get('school_address')
            user.student.country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
            user.student.state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
            user.student.communication_address = form.cleaned_data.get('communication_address')
            user.student.c_country = form.cleaned_data.get('c_country')
            user.student.c_state = form.cleaned_data.get('c_state')
            user.student.grade = form.cleaned_data.get('grade')
            user.student.cost = form.cleaned_data.get('cost')
            user.student.total = form.cleaned_data.get('total')
            user.student.type_user = form.cleaned_data.get('type_user')
            user.student.currency=form.cleaned_data.get('currency_code')

            user.student.save()  # this will save the Student data

            subject = 'Registration Successfull'
            message = 'You have successfully completed registration....'+'\n'+'Username:' +user.username+'\n'+ 'Password:' +user.password
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [user.email]
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Registration Successfull .. Check E-mail for credentials')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
            return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html', {'form': form,'countries':countryobj})
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        print("lalala")
        # return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html')
        print(countryobj)
        return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html',{'form':form,'countries':countryobj})
```